# How do I execute a function that receives handles as an argument, in another GUI?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm trying to change my plot in my main GUI according to a different number of options that I've put in another GUI. So, the main objective of this is to press the "OK" button on my second GUI, and that automatically changes the plot of the main one. I've already defined a function that does all that in my main GUI, and I wanted to use it on my second one.

Basically, I'm trying to use a function from one GUI to another and that function receives handles as its only argument.

Here's a bit of what I want

Main GUI - plotGraphs(handles) - This is the function in my main GUI that plots a graphic, according to several defined global variables.

Second GUI - Changes some of those global variables. Pressing "OK", the function plotGraphs is called and should change the Main GUI, according to the new variables.

I just don't know how to do this. I've tried putting this into the "OK" button callback

```
plotGraphs(handles)
close(secondGUI);
```

And it does not work. I've also tried passing the handles from the Main GUI to the second, but that does not seem to work either, or maybe I'm doing something wrong. Also, I'm using GUIDE for my GUI.

Comment: Try using global variables. In my experience this has worked for a very similar situation as yours.

Comment: I've also tried setting the handles for the main GUI as a global, and passing it as an argument when calling the function in the second one, but it doesn't work. I get this error
"??? Undefined function or method 'plotGraphs' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'." or this one 
"??? Undefined function or method 'plotGraphs' for input arguments of type 'struct'."

Comment: Don't pass that as argument! Just define it as global in each of the function that uses it!